# How to disable autofill in chrome v72.0.3626.109 non-input password

Tags: html, google-chrome, autofill

After update chrome to version 72.0.3626.109, tag autocomplete off stopped work,

I'm trying use autocomplete='somestring', but not work.

Follow the image:
[image: So]
I tried autocomplete="false", autocomplete="off" and plugin for disable autofill, use jQuery to add attribute autocomplete, but not worked!

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I went through a similar issue the past few days. In my case what was causing that strange behavior was a pdf viewer (pdfjs). As soon as I moved the viewer outside of the form element, the issue disappeared. Loading the viewer inside an iframe also solved it. I don't know the root cause but it was definitely that.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with something very similar and found this question while I was searching for answers, here's how I fixed it.

My situation: I have an input field for searching, and somewhere else I had a username and password field. Chrome recently started putting the autocompleted username in the search field.

Apparently, Chrome ignores autocomplete="off" now, and goes by the string value to try to determine what type of data to autocomplete. So if you have a search box, you should put autocomplete="search" so Chrome won't put the username in there, for example.

When I first noticed a long time ago autocomplete="off" was being ignored for my search box, I switched to autocomplete="search" and that worked. Now, Chrome started putting the username in the search box again with the latest update.

The way to fix this, if your situation is similar, is to put the autocomplete field for *all* of your text inputs with a string describing what it is.

**BEFORE:**

```
<input id='search' type='text' autocomplete="search">
```

And somewhere else on the page...

```
<input id='login_username' type='text'>
<input id='login_password' type='password'>
```

**AFTER**

```
<input id='search' type='text' autocomplete="search">
```

And somewhere else on the page...

```
<input id='login_username' type='text' autocomplete="username">
<input id='login_password' type='password' autocomplete="password">
```

Additionally, putting the inputs in a form also affects the autocomplete, but I didn't have too much time to mess with that and I needed a quick fix to get my site working properly again. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Also using autocomplete="custom_input" makes the input autocomplete off since in some situations, the input might be a CRM custom field like the email, and should not be auto filled, since changes from client to client record.

Comment: the problem is because chrome ignore autocomplete="CUSTOM_STRING" and show de password, for me this is a critical BUG of CHROME, showing your save password in input type text, this is terrible.